# Selenium C# Auto generated Code for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, selenium, integration-testing

I would like to test a Website UI.

Is it possible to record all Website clicked elements using Visual Studio 2010 (just like Selenium IDE does)?

Is there a integration between *Visual Studio 2010* and *Selenium* in order to use Selenium auto generated C# code inside VS2010?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

The way I have done this is record the test in Selenium IDE and save as C# and NUnit.  NUnit asserts are almost identical to MSTest unit tests.  I then paste into a Visual Studio unit test and hand modify the small number of deficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

The Selenium equivalent in VS is inside the Team System / Test edition component.

The allows you to capture a "webtest" by clicking a workflow inside IE and then (if you want) running a series of these webtests as a "loadtest".

All the webtests can be run on their own or you can link a few of them together to approximate a Selenium Test Suite.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new **Format** for export using Options->Formats->Source (button). Copy the existing `C# (Remote Control)` entry and alter the java to output MSTest tests. It's pretty easy.